# Linker errors with ADODB exist in one project on one machine, but not others

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, adodb

We have a large solution (195 projects) and on one of the projects I'm getting 17 linker errors (LNK2001 and LNK2019), however the source is checked out from subversion and nobody else on the team gets these errors.  I've already verified that the project properties match up between computers, the only significant difference I know of is that I'm the only one on Windows 7 32-bit.

All of the errors are in relation to methods with `ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConnection` as the first parameter, if I take this out then the errors go away.

I'm confused since this is the only machine having problems building the project, so I imagine no definitions need to be added to get this to work.  There are other projects in this solution with similar `ADODB::_ConnectionPtr` method parameters that are compiling properly on my machine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you are using the same version of the compiler and the other build tools? Is the missing (incomplete) object-file containing the relevant code even compiled (on your machine)? When should it be linked? I would say that there are to many possibilities what could go wrong, and if this is not somehow a really known error helping you is like finding a needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the project properties in VS2005 didn't reflect the individual file properties.  I had _MAKE_ADO_IMPORT_ as a preprocessor definition for the project, but it only showed up in 9 of the 12 cpp file properties.  I individually added it as a preprocessor definition to each file and the linker errors suddenly disappeared.

What confuses me more is the fact that this was checked out of subversion and was not the same on other developers' machines.